# django print all record in the cmd but display the last one on template

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates, fetchall

i have a function that retrieve data from sql server database where i am using **fetchall()** then  for loop 
the retrieved data are all printed on the **cmd console** but when i tried to display these result on the template it **only display the last record**.

## views.py

def search(request):

```
  query = cursor.execute('Select id, fullname from person')
  result = query.fetchall()
  for row in result:
    print("ID==>",id)
    IPD=row[0]
  return render(request,"test.html",{"IPD":IPD})
```

## test.html

```
  {{ IPD }}
```

Comment: `result` contains all of your results, `IPD` is reassigned every iteration of your for loop so will be whatever was assigned in the last iteration -> the last item in `results`

Comment: so what you say if want just to get all ID  i wrote `result[0]`?

Comment: Just return `result`. I would recommend using Django's ORM though if you are using Django

Comment: i can't use ORM I am using raw sql with sql server database --- if i return result it will contains all fields where what i want is just to return the IDs off all records

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/

Comment: well i am using pyodbc-azure--- but still not getting the answer to my question

Comment: You can certainly use the ORM with PyODBC. See for example https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/

Answer (score 0):

```
 query = cursor.execute('Select id, fullname from person')
 result = query.fetchall()
 IPD=[]
 for row in result:
     print("ID==>",id)
     IPD.append(row)
 return render(request,"test.html",{"IPD":IPD})
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.